# Generate a time series for a buffer point on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer, time-series

I am trying to extract the time series of soil moisture by applying a 500 m radius buffer to the point defined by mapping the bufferPoints function over the FeatureCollection, using the following code:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-8.620027,31.363085]); 

function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
  return function(pt) {
    pt = ee.Feature(pt);
    return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
  };
}
var ptsbuff = point.map(bufferPoints(500, false));

// Create a chart for SoilMoi100_200cm_inst trend in point 1.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
          .filterBounds(ptsbuff)
          .filterDate('2006-01-01', '2016-12-31')
          .select('SoilMoi100_200cm_inst');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var start_year = 2006;
var start_date = '2006-01-01';
var end_year = 2016;
var end_date = '2016-12-31';

var years = ee.List.sequence( start_year, end_year);


var byMonthYear =  ee.FeatureCollection(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var w = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .mean();
           
      var pointMean = w.reduceRegion({reducer:ee.Reducer.first(), geometry:ptsbuff,scale:25000});  
      // set the dictionary as property and cast to an ee.Image, as setMulti returns an ee.Element.
      return ee.Feature(null).set("value",pointMean.get("SoilMoi100_200cm_inst")).set("year",y).set("month",m);
      

    });
  }).flatten()
);


// print the collection, point information
print("feature collection",byMonthYear);

Export.table.toDrive({collection:byMonthYear,description:"csvExport"})
```

However, it seems that there is a problem in my code as it gives me this error message:
Line 9: point.map is not a function

It should be noted that when I apply the buffer function on a point in shapefile format the code works well, I think the problem is related to that but I do not know how or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because 'point' isn't a `FeatureCollection` but an object. You can't map a function over a single object; only over collections (e.g. a `FeatureCollection`). You can change it to a FC by:

```
var ptsbuff = ee.FeatureCollection(point).map(bufferPoints(500, false));
```

Or just add the buffer directly to the point

```
var pointWithBuffer = point.buffer(500)
```

Edit to answer your comment: to make sure the reducer returns a value, reduce the scale to something smaller or equal as the geometry (ie. the buffered point):

```
var pointMean = w.reduceRegion({reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry:ptsbuff,scale:500});
```

Comment: Both solutions work well, but in the CSV results I do not get the soil moisture value, I only get the month and year...

Comment: That's probably because the scale of your reducer is larger than the geometry of the buffered point.

Comment: Indeed it was that. Thank you.